# How to validate the change address in a multisig transaction?

Tags: multi-signature, change

I am using Specter Desktop to create a PSBT for a multisig transaction with some hardware wallets to sign. Part of the PSBT is a change address and I can match what the hardware wallet says to what Specter Desktop intends, but since I don't trust Specter Desktop 100% how can I validate that this change address derives from my multisig wallet?

Answer (score 1):

I went and RTFM and found a sufficient answer: Using the proper change-address descriptor for the wallet, I called `deriveaddresses` and I see the corresponding change address returned from bitcoin core.